# How to do a syncdb with django, when migrations are also involved

Tags: django, django-models, django-south, django-syncdb

when I do a syncdb I get the following error everytime:

```
Not synced (use migrations):
 - deals
 - analytics
(use ./manage.py migrate to migrate these)
```

And when I run sudo python manage.py migrate. I get the following

```
Running migrations for deals:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for deals.
No fixtures found.
Running migrations for analytics:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for analytics.
No fixtures found.
```

I highly appreciate your help

Comment: Your django project is using a third party app called south which takes over from syncdb for a selected set of apps and handles things like schema migrations in the database. Read the docs on south for more info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the output, it seems like the database is **already synchronized with the migrations**. There are no problematic errors. (Although you shouldn't really be root to run the migrations.)

If you're looking into creating more migrations, use the [south documentation](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/tutorial/part1.html#changing-the-model), which usually is just running the following after you modify the models:

```
python manage.py schemamigration --auto <APP>
```

And then use `python manage.py migrate` to apply the changes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like migrations have been already passed. Check south_migationhistory table in db.

If you want to sync new db for apps which has migrations just disable south in settings.py.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ran a schemamigration initial yet?

```
./manage.py schemamigration deals --initial
./manage.py migrate deals
```

if you get the error, db already excists do this:

```
./manage.py schemamigration deals --initial
./manage.py migrate deals --fake
```